# String tokenizing in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, stringtokenizer

When I run this program the button for tokenize is not working
I don't know why?
Is there any changes?

```
Private Sub Tokenize_Click()       
    Dim tok As New Tokenizer      
    Dim s As String      

    tok.init txString.Text  
    lsTokens.Clear          
    s = tok.nextToken       

    While Len(s)>0        
        lsTokens.AddItem s    
        s = tok.nextToken     
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: The "Handles..." clause is missing

Comment: Already tried it with split() instead of the tokenizer?

Comment: That isn't VB.NET - there is no `Wend` keyword used in VB.NET (although it is [retained as reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/)).

Comment: The code is probably VB6 or VBA not vb.net. Change the tag and title, please.

Answer (score 0):

'You missed (Handles) at the end of the first line of the code (Change it like this):

```
Private Sub Tokenize_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tokenize.Click
```

Comment: There is no `Handles` in VBA. I'm waiting for the OP to figure out if they are trying to translate from VBA to VB.NET or if they are trying to write in VBA. Also, the tag [tag:stringtokenizer] is for a particular Java class.

Comment: OK, Change the title Because you are asking for VBA not VB.net.